# Pl/SQL Cursor Compilation Error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I wrote a very simple PL/SQL code to remove some of the scheduled jobs .Below is the code

```
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
Declare
v_job_id user_jobs.job%type;
cursor jobs is
select job  from user_jobs where what like 'ABC%';
begin

                  for j in jobs
                  loop
                  dbms_job.remove(j.job);
                  end loop;

Exception
When others then 
Insert into TEMP values(TEMP_SEQ.nextval,2,'00remove_db_jobs.sql','','',sysdate,sysdate,'AUTO','ERROR');    
end;
```

But I am getting a compilation error "no data found". How to tackle this compilation error any suggestions .I am using Oracle database.

Comment: Well first of all when you execute the query `select job  from user_jobs where what like 'ABC%';`is anything returned?

Comment: executing select job from user_jobs where what like 'ABC%'; returned nothing which can be a valid case. I want my code to handle this

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the NO_DATA_FOUND exception. [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)